Karma: Cannot load browser "EdgeHeadless": it is not registered! Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
I want to run karma without opening the browser, and I'm getting an error and I don't know how to make it work.
Windows, Angular, Karma, Jasmine, and Edge
karma.conf.js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-edge-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/your-project-name'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'coverage-istanbul'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['EdgeHeadless'],
    singleRun: true,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
    customLaunchers: {
      EdgeHeadless: {
        base: 'Edge',
        flags: ['--headless']
      }
    }
  });
};

devDependencies
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.2.6",
"@angular/cli": "18.1.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "18.1.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
"esbuild-visualizer": "^0.6.0",
"husky": "^9.1.6",
"jasmine-core": "^5.3.0",
"karma": "^6.4.4",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
"karma-edge-launcher": "^0.4.2",
"karma-jasmine": "^5.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
"prettier": "^3.3.3",
"typescript": "~5.5.3"

}
When I run: npx karma start --single-run --browsers EdgeHeadless
I get those logs
 26 09 2024 20:52:54.925:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.4.4 server
 started at http://localhost:9876/ 26 09 2024 20:52:54.931:INFO
 [launcher]: Launching browsers EdgeHeadless with concurrency unlimited
 26 09 2024 20:52:54.933:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot load browser
 "EdgeHeadless": it is not registered! Perhaps you are missing some
 plugin? 26 09 2024 20:52:54.934:ERROR [karma-server]: Error: Found 1
 load error
     at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\x9cinc\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\6b5b01ae7908e427\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:243:26)
     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:633:28)
     at Server.emit (node:events:531:35)
     at emitListeningNT (node:net:1947:10)
     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)

